# After showing an warning message how to save the record stick on that particular condition in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo-9

I did this to my code

```
def unicode_warning(self):
  if not self.barcode:
    raise UserError(_('Unicode Missing'))
```

It is showing warning message perfectly.But I want after the warning message it would let me save the record without the 'barcode' field.Is that possible?I am working on odoo9. Please help

Comment: Ohh thanks,I didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

This should be your python code

```
@api.multi
    @api.onchange('barcode')
    @api.depends('barcode')
    def onchange_unicode_warning(self):
        lic = {}
        if not self.barcode:
            lic['warning'] = {'title': 'Information','message': 'Barcode Code is Missing'}
        return lic
```

and the xml code should be:-

```
             <field name="arch" type="xml">
                 <field name="barcode" position="attributes">
                     <attribute name="onchange">onchange_unicode_warning(barcode)</attribute>
                 </field>
             </field>
```

This way you can only display warning without the prevention of record saving.